# Kivy transitions turning off except for the first

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy

I am working on a simple login screen for kivy. I want to turn off the transitions between the screens because I don't think it fits the aesthetic, but the first animation always goes through, even if I disable it. Is this something to do with kivy or am I doing it wrong? Here is the code.

Python Code
VVVVVVVVVV

```py
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder

class LoginWindow(Screen):
    username = ObjectProperty(None)
    password = ObjectProperty(None)

    def btn(self):
        print(self.username.text, self.password.text)


class CreateWindow(Screen):
    pass


class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

kv = Builder.load_file("login.kv")

class LoginApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv


if __name__ == "__main__":
    #kivy has a default app class, so no need to create one
    LoginApp().run()
```

.kv Code
VVVVVVVV

```
WindowManager:
    LoginWindow:
    CreateWindow:


<LoginWindow>:
    name: "login"
    username: username
    password: password

    FloatLayout:
        Button:
            text:"Log In"
            size_hint: 0.5, 0.1
            pos_hint: {"x":0.25, "y":0.3}
            on_press: root.btn()
        
        Button:
            text:"Create Account"
            size_hint: 0.3, 0.05
            pos_hint: {"x":0.36, "y":0.20}
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "Create"
                root.manager.transition = NoTransition()
        
        TextInput:
            id: password
            size_hint: 0.25, 0.1
            pos_hint: {"x":0.5, "y":0.5}
        
        TextInput:
            id:username
            size_hint: 0.25, 0.1
            pos_hint: {"x":0.5, "y":0.6}
        
        Label:
            font_size: '40'
            text:"Log In"
            size_hint: 0.5, 0.5
            pos_hint: {"x":0.25, "y":0.6}
        
        Label:
            font_size: '25'
            text:"Username:"
            size_hint: 0.5, 0.1
            pos_hint:{"x":0.1,"y":0.6}
        
        Label:
            font_size: '25'
            text:"Password:"
            size_hint: 0.5, 0.1
            pos_hint:{"x":0.1,"y":0.5}

<CreateWindow>:
    name: "Create"

    Button:
        #: import NoTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.NoTransition
        transition: NoTransition()
        text: "Go Back"
        on_release:
            app.root.current = "login"
            root.manager.transition = NoTransition()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can turn off transitions by adding it to your `WindowManager:` rule:

```
WindowManager:
    transition: NoTransition()
    LoginWindow:
    CreateWindow:
```

The other uses of `NoTransition()` can then be removed.